# how to Disable a dropdown value when a value is selected from another drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have two dropdown lists and both dropdown lists contain same values(madurai,coimbatore,chennai)
example:
if i select value (madurai) in first dropdown then same value  in another dropdown list is need to be disable..please help me

```html
<div class="dropdown pull-right dropdown_custom quarter_from }}">
      <span>from</span>
      <button class="btn dropdown-supply dropdown-toggle dropdown-site select_txt_from" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select
      <div style="float:right"><span class="caret"></span></div></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu_custom">
          <li>coimbatore</li>
          <li>madurai</li>
          <li>chennai</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div class="dropdown pull-right dropdown_custom quarter_from }}">
      <span>from</span>
      <button class="btn dropdown-supply dropdown-toggle dropdown-site select_txt_from" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select
      <div style="float:right"><span class="caret"></span></div></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu_custom">
          <li>coimbatore</li>
          <li>madurai</li>
          <li>chennai</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<select id="one">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Coimbatore</option>
  <option value="2">Madurai</option>
  <option value="3">Chennai</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Coimbatore</option>
  <option value="2">Madurai</option>
  <option value="3">Chennai</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#one").on('change', function() {
$('#two option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected')
  $('#two option').attr("disabled", false);
  var selected = $('#one option:selected').val();
  if(selected !=0)
  $('#two option[value="' + selected + '"]').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/pov6dvx9/1/)</kbd>

Comment: this code working bt instead of select and option elament i have to use li element

Comment: Are you using that dropdown in the menu ?

Comment: ya..i used bootsrap dropdown class in my ul element..(<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu_custom">) @Hazard

Comment: I am asking that where you are gonna put this dropdown in your application ?

Comment: I dont understand ur question @Hazard

Comment: in my application i have to select from and to place..so i need this

Comment: Why don't you use select ? ul li dropdowns are for links

Comment: ok i will try to use select element @hazard.. is it possible to disable values by using li element?

Answer (score 0):

You could add/remove the items to their respective dropdown menu based upon the changing values from the other selection.

To be more clear, when the first selection is changed, read the value of the selected option then use that value to remove/disable that item from the second dropdown-menu. You would also need to be making sure that you're displaying the other 2 options (If you're removing them from the dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

**Html Code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Js Code**

```
 jQuery('#select1').on('change', function() {
  var opt=this.value ;
  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
  jQuery('#select2 option[value="'+opt+'"]').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

You can view demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/2fv4y19h/)

Comment: this code working bt instead of select and option elament i have to use li element

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap dropdown is not really made for this purpose, but if you really want to use that, you can use jQuery to detect which item is selected in the first list and to add class disabled to the corresponding item in the second list.

Code below is an example, but is not tested!

```html
<div id="d1" class="dropdown pull-right dropdown_custom quarter_from }}">
      <span>from</span>
      <button class="btn dropdown-supply dropdown-toggle dropdown-site select_txt_from" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select
      <div style="float:right"><span class="caret"></span></div></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu_custom">
          <li>coimbatore</li>
          <li>madurai</li>
          <li>chennai</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div id="d2" class="dropdown pull-right dropdown_custom quarter_from }}">
      <span>from</span>
      <button class="btn dropdown-supply dropdown-toggle dropdown-site select_txt_from" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select
      <div style="float:right"><span class="caret"></span></div></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu_custom">
          <li>coimbatore</li>
          <li>madurai</li>
          <li>chennai</li>
      </ul>
    </div>    

<script>

$("#d1 li").click(function(e) {
    text = $(this).text();
    $('#d2 li').each(function(index, item) {
        if($(item).text() == text) {
            $(item).addClass("disabled");
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Take out the extra `(` in `($(this).text();` (cant make edit myself b/c it needs to be more than 6 characters)